# How to test async methods with Moq and xUnit

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, moq, xunit

I am having the following method which calls an insert and update methods.

Conditions

1. In the below `ProcessBspLoan` function, I am calling other function named `getBspData`
   if `getBspData` returns any result. I will **insert** the result
   and **update** the database as a success for a particular Id
2. if `getBspData` throws any Exception I will only **update** the database as a fail for a particular Id without **inserting**

Here is the ProcessBspLoan function in the given class

```
    public class BspLoanProcessor : IBspLoanProcessor
    {
        private readonly IBspClient _bspService;
        private readonly IBspRepository _bspRepository;
        private readonly ILogger<BspLoanProcessor> _logger;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;
        private readonly IFhaRepository _fhaRepository;

        public BspLoanProcessor(IBspClient bspService, ILogger<BspLoanProcessor> logger, 
            IMapper mapper, IBspRepository bSPRepository, IFhaRepository fhaRepository)
        {
            _bspService = bspService;
            _logger = logger;
            _mapper = mapper;
            _bspRepository = bSPRepository;
            _fhaRepository = fhaRepository;
        }

        public async Task<bool> ProcessBspLoan(BspLoanDetails bspLoanDetails, string transactionId, string triggerType)
        {
            FhaTransactionDetails fhaData = _mapper.Map<FhaTransactionDetails>(bspLoanDetails);

            try
            {
                ////////////////////////////Calling getBspData///////////////////////////////////////
                var result = await _bspService.getBspData(bspLoanDetails.NsmLoanNumber, transactionId);

                result.TransactionId = transactionId;

                await _bspRepository.InsertBspResponse(result);
                
                await _fhaRepository.UpdateFhaTransactionWithLoanNumber(transactionId,"SUCCESS");
                return true;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                await _fhaRepository.UpdateFhaTransactionWithLoanNumber(transactionId,"FAIL");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

I wrote the test method for the above function want to check it is returning true or false based on inputs provided

Here is my test function

```
    public async Task Test1Async()
    {
        Mock<IBspLoanProcessor> _bspLoanProcessor = new Mock<IBspLoanProcessor>();
        Mock<IBspRepository> _bspRepository = new Mock<IBspRepository>();
        Mock<IFhaRepository> _fhaRepository = new Mock<IFhaRepository>();
        Mock<IBspClient> _bspClient = new Mock<IBspClient>();
        BspLoanDetails bspLoanDetails = new BspLoanDetails
        {
            TriggerType = "BLOB",
            Attempts = 1,
            FirstRunDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()
        };
        ----> 1
        _bspClient.Setup(x => x.getBspData(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(Task.FromResult(new BspResponseDetails()));
        ----> 2
        _bspRepository.Setup(x => x.InsertBspResponse(It.IsAny<BspResponseDetails>())).Returns(Task.CompletedTask);
        ----> 3
        _fhaRepository.Setup(x => x.UpdateFhaTransactionWithLoanNumber(It.IsAny<string>(),It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(Task.CompletedTask);
        bool value = await _bspLoanProcessor.Object.ProcessBspLoan(bspLoanDetails, "123", "SCHEDULE");
        Assert.True(value);
    }
```

In the above the test, I am checking the first condition

1. I am returning data as an object whenever anyone called gets data
2. Inserting `BspResponsemethod` also I am returning `task.completedTask`
3. `UpdateFhaTransactionWithLoanNumber` also I am returning `task.completedTask`

The actual expected output is true, but it is returning false.

I am new to Moq and xUnit. Please help me to resolve this issue and also test async and await methods.

IBspClient interface

```
    public interface IBspClient
    {
        Task<BspResponseDetails> getBspData(string loanNumber,string tid);

        Task<BspHealthCheck> GetHealthStatus();
    }
```

IBspRepository Interface

```
    public interface IBspRepository
    {
        Task InsertBspResponse(BspResponseDetails bsp);
    }
```

IFhaRepository interface

```
    public interface IFhaRepository
    {
        Task UpdateFhaTransactionWithLoanNumber(string tid, string status);    
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is '_mapper'? I presume it is an 'Automapper' (or something similar) instance defining how to map source to destination. If it is, from standards perspective, should it not be injected in method signature of 'ProcessBspLoan'? I am trying your code but realised that mapper object becomes a dependency that cannot be injected in test from outside. Unless ofcourse you are taking care of it at the class level. Also, can you provide definitions of other dependencies like repository and _bspService class etc?

Comment: _mapper is an automapper, I am handling classlevel
public BspLoanProcessor(IBspClient bspService, ILogger<BspLoanProcessor> logger, 
            IMapper mapper, IBspRepository bSPRepository, IFhaRepository fhaRepository)
        {
            _bspService = bspService;
            _logger = logger;
            _mapper = mapper;
            _bspRepository = bSPRepository;
            _fhaRepository = fhaRepository;
        }

Comment: sure I will edit the question and provide each and every interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `bool value = await _bspLoanProcessor.Object`

You're calling a method on your mock. You shouldn't mock the system-under-test, you only mock its dependencies.

Just `new` the class you want to test, otherwise you will be testing that your mock framework does what you set it up to.

And because you didn't setup `ProcessBspLoan()`, it returns the default for its return value, so `false`.

Comment: Ooh okay, I will check once

Comment: Thank you knowledge transfer